# SF2 Twig : How to customize rendering of CoolectionType embedded in CollectionType?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, themes

I'm designing an app with a Survey entity. Each survey can have multiple SurveyQuestion entities (CollectionType in form, attribute Survey->questions) and each SurveyQuestion can have multiple SurveyAnswer entities (SurveyQuestion->availableAnswers).

Forms are logically spread in SurveyType, QuestionType and AnswerType.

**How can I set template fragment for availableAnswers?**

I looked around 2 leads :

**First, form_theme targeting specific type : in Survey form twig**

```
 {# Theming for questions #}
 {% form_theme form.questions 'LCHModuleBundle:Survey/form:question.html.twig' %}

 {# Theming for answers #}
{#{% form_theme form.availableAnswers 'LCHModuleBundle:Survey/form:answer.html.twig' %}#}
```

*Looks impossible to access availableQuestions because it's a field from one item of questions collection.*

**Second, block naming (according to [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field)) :**

In Survey form twig  :

```
{% form_theme form with ['LCHModuleBundle:Survey/form:question.html.twig', 'LCHModuleBundle:Survey/form:answer.html.twig'] %}
```

- For question

In question.html.twig :

```
{#Question list rendering#}
{% block _lchmodule_bundle_survey_type_questions_widget %}...{% endblock %}
```

In QuestionType :

```
class QuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    const NAME= "lchmodule_bundle_question_type";.

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }
}
```

- For answer

In answer.html.twig :

```
{% block _lchmodule_bundle_answer_type_availableAnswers_widget %}...{% endblock %}
```

In AnswerType :

```
class AnswerType extends AbstractType
{
    const NAME = "lchmodule_bundle_answer_type";
   /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return self::NAME;
    }
}
```

THeming is working great for questions, but not for answers. How can I access availableQuestions theming regarding the fact that it's an embedded CollectionType within an CollectionType?

Thanks for your lights,

Nicolas

Comment: You should loop through `collection type` field and inside the loop, include a separate twig file, where you can have child form. Pass the necessary param. Then inside the included twig file, set your `form_theme` as required.

Comment: Thank you very much ! this worked. Could you put an answer I could mark as good one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the main form, print your collection items as :

```
{% for collectionItem in form.collections %}
    {% include 'AppBundle:Blog:collection.item.html.twig' %}
{% endfor %}
```

so that the colleciton items can be in separate twig file. Now in separate twig file (`collection.item.html.twig`), define your `form_theme` or do necessary changes.

hope this helps.